# Very simple 2d and 3d graphics library

Tags: c#, .net, graphics, 3d

I have to create library that render static, simple shapes with some 3d effects such as rotation and bevels. Shapes can contains text or image on it.
Something similar to this:
[image]

I think that with GDI+ it will be hard to implement so is there any CLS compliant library that will help me with rendering?

P.S. I can not use WPF.

Comment: GDI+ is fine in this case. Generating a realistic shade for a 3D effect is going to be the hard part, but not impossible.

Comment: Examples of something similar with GDI+ will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Second that - i've actually written a small 3d engine with lighting and transforms using GDI+.  It isn't easy, but can be done.

Comment: I think I'd go GDI+ for that kind of effects. Not easy, but not that hard either.

Answer (score 5):

Try to read the following stackoverflow page to choose the engine:

[What to use? Tao, SharpGL, OpenTK, DirectX P/Invoke, XNA, MDX, SlimDX, Windows API Codec Pack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4885085/what-to-use-tao-sharpgl-opentk-directx-p-invoke-xna-mdx-slimdx-windows-ap)

One example for the Tao framework with C# can be found in codeproject:
[OpenGL 3D Navigation with Tao and C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/openGL/OpenGLNavigationTaoCSharp.aspx)

Comment: +1 for OpenTK - great library. Also most of OpenGL tutorial can be applied while learning it :)

Answer (score 1):

You could try SFML: [main page](http://www.sfml-dev.org/) - [features (includes bindings)](http://www.sfml-dev.org/features.php).

It's got a Shape primitive, is based on OpenGL rendering and includes support for shaders.

Comment: Not bad by description, but in samples they uses Tao for drawing and library is written in C++.

Comment: It's written in C++ but offers .NET bindings. It may not be what you're looking for.